# How to get a WCF service to work (not have 404) within an MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I am a noob with MVC and with WCF.  I have an MVC application (called RewardsMVC) in which I want to add a WCF service. I created a folder called "Services" within my MVC application and added a WCF Service (called wcfMain)
I added a line in my RouteConfig.cs class

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RewardsMVC/Services", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Services.wcfMain)));
```

I have two simple functions within my wcfMain.svc (and IwcfMain.cs)

When I added my WCF service this was added to my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

So here are the dumb questions:
When I try to navigate to the wcfMain.svc IE gives a 404 error.
I have tried "http://localhost/Rewards/Services/wcfMain.svc", "http://localhost/Rewards/wcfMain" and a few other variations.  I always get the 404 error.

What do I need to change/add in order to display/access the two functions within this web service?

BTW I am used to "old school" asp.net and asmx web services.

Comment: I believe you would want to modify your Route to be an 'ignore' on the /Services/ path.  This will prevent the MVC stack from trying to bind said request.

Comment: I commented out the "serviceroute" line and tried:    routes.IgnoreRoute("RewardsMVC/Services"); and    routes.Ignore("RewardsMVC/Services");  However I still get a 404 error when trying to reach "http://localhost/FHS/RewardsMVC/Services/wcfMain.svc"     I also added "FHS" in front but it did not make a difference

Comment: the route would be more along the lines of routes.IgnoreRoute("RewardsMVC/Services/{*pathInfo}"); Also - you would want this above any other route statement in the RegisterRoutes(); to verify it is really getting ignored, try a static html page (like static.htm) or image and try to link to that

Comment: I added the line you suggested above all others and still get a 404 error which shows "Requested URL: /FHS/RewardsMVC/Services/wcfMain.svc" not found.    The path is correct the error is displaying.

Comment: can you be more specific about why/where the leading FHS/ is coming from in the path?

Comment: Yes.  The application is within a subfolder in IIS.    The application path is http://localhost/FHS/RewardsMVC.   the "FHS" is a subfolder where several other web applications reside.   This MVC app is intended to replace an older "Rewards" asp.net webforms app. which is why I added the "MVC" to this one.   I placed the wcfMain.svc under a folder in RewardsMVC called "Services."  I hope that made sense.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions on what might work.  In the past, I've tackled this issue by having a separate WCF project within the solution.  It was then deployed 'next' to the MVC app and common code was in a shared assembly.  The alternative would be to migrate to using MVC's WebApi framework.  Good luck!

Comment: I've decided to switch to using a webapi and drop the WCF so back to the drawing board.  Thanks for the input though!